# Can we single step QEMU using libvert

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I am developing a peripheral hardware and want to use QEMU to test it.

The plan is to run the device driver in QEMU and use libvert (or something else?) to interface the VM with a python based simulation model of the peripheral. 
I aware that QEMU can be single stepped via GDB, but I am looking at a python approach to do the following.

1. Wait for a write to a specific memory location.
2. Suspend QEMU
3. Run some background task in the host.
4. Run QEMU for N Cycles.
5. Write to a memory location
6. Continue

Is this possible with libvert or any other toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, and came across two approaches:

1. Run Python in GDB, using a python script of the commands
2. Use a Python API to GDB like pygdbmi

The latter ended up being more flexible, so I'll explain those steps here.
Configure qemu with debugging information:

```
./configure --enable-debug
```

Build qemu and invoke it halted, with debug hooks:

```sh
make
sudo make install
qemu-system-x86_64 -S -s
```

Now, use a Python script to attach to and interact with qemu via pygdbmi([instructions here](https://github.com/cs01/pygdbmi)):

```py
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController
from pprint import pprint

# Start gdb process
gdbmi = GdbController()
print(gdbmi.get_subprocess_cmd())  # print actual command run as subprocess

gdbmi.write('target remote localhost:1234');  # attach to QEMU GDB socket
pprint(response)
response = gdbmi.write('-break-insert main')  # machine interface (MI) commands start with a '-'
response = gdbmi.write('break main')  # normal gdb commands work too, but the return value is slightly different
response = gdbmi.write('-exec-run')
response = gdbmi.write('run')
response = gdbmi.write('-exec-next', timeout_sec=0.1)  # the wait time can be modified from the default of 1 second
response = gdbmi.write('next')
response = gdbmi.write('next', raise_error_on_timeout=False)
response = gdbmi.write('next', raise_error_on_timeout=True, timeout_sec=0.01)
response = gdbmi.write('-exec-continue')
response = gdbmi.send_signal_to_gdb('SIGKILL')  # name of signal is okay
response = gdbmi.send_signal_to_gdb(2)  # value of signal is okay too
response = gdbmi.interrupt_gdb()  # sends SIGINT to gdb
response = gdbmi.write('si 20') # step 20 instructions
response = gdbmi.write('continue')
response = gdbmi.exit()
```

If you have trouble with kernel symbols, you might also need to issue a command 'file myKernel' to load the symbol table from that file, assuming it was compiled with debugging information.

For reference, the '-s' command adds GDB hooks at localhost:1234.  So the first command you issue must direct gdb to look there:

```py
gdbmi.write('target remote localhost:1234');
```